# How to tell MVVMLight create a new view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I am using MvvmLight in a WPF project, and have set up my view model locator as shown in their examples...

```
public class ViewModelLocator {
  public ViewModelLocator() {
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainWindowViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ProductDetailsWindowViewModel>();
  }

  public MainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel =>
    SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MainWindowViewModel>();
  public ProductDetailsWindowViewModel ProductDetailsWindowViewModel => 
    SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ProductDetailsWindowViewModel>();
}
```

I have the following line in the opening tag of my XAML...

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator},
    Path=ProductDetailsWindowViewModel}"
```

This works, but the locator always returns the same view model, ie the same instance, meaning that if I have more than one product details window open, they will all share the same view model.

How do I tell MvvmLight to create a new view model when I request one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We always use Ninject, which seems to do what you want by default:-

First, add a reference to the Nuget package for [Ninject](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject/)

Then add a `ViewModelLocator` class to your project and use code like the following...

```
public class ViewModelLocator {
  public IKernel Kernel { get; set; }

  public ViewModelLocator() {
    Kernel = new StandardKernel();
  }

  public MainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel =>
    Kernel.Get<MainWindowViewModel>();
  public ProductDetailsWindowViewModel ProductDetailsWindowViewModel =>
    Kernel.Get<ProductDetailsWindowViewModel>();
}
```

Add a static resource for the locator in App.xaml as follows...

```
<Application.Resources>
  <viewModels:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Make sure your view models inherit from `ViewModelBase`...

```
public class ProductDetailsWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
  // ...
```

Then your `DataContext` should work as you want. Each window will get its own instance of the class.

One thing you need to make sure here is to clean up after yourself, otherwise you end up with loads of ghost view models hanging around. In your window's Unloading event, set the `DataContext` to null...

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
  DataContext = null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll start using Ninject now, since that seems to be the way forward for me.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I tell MvvmLight to create a new view model when I request one?

Use the overload of the `GetInstance` method that acceps a `string` and pass a unique `string` value to it:

```
public MainViewModel Main =>
    ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

Comment: This works well too. I am going to start using Ninject though. Thanks.

Comment: @Joe: That's fine but what does NInject have to do with your original question?

Comment: Ninject does all of this automatically. Plus it makes unit testing much simpler. So if this sorts out my problem, and it is a package that I want to start using, then I'll go for that. Your answer works too.

Comment: But still @mm8's answer is the answer to this question, so I think it should be accepted instead.